# ¿Cómo puedo tokenizar un string en C ++?

Tags: c++, string, tokens

Java tiene un método `split` conveniente para separar una cadena de texto en tokens:

```
String str = "wiki de comunidad";
String[] results = str.split(" ");
```

¿Hay una manera fácil de hacer esto en C++?

Comment: la voto, por que igual despues se te van a descontar los puntos !

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: ¿porque votan para cerrar la pregunta?

Answer (score 8):

**Autor original**

> Konrad Rudolph https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph

Su simple caso puede ser fácilmente construido utilizando el método [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) . Sin embargo, eche un vistazo a [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html). Es genial. Boost generalmente tiene algunas herramientas de cadena muy buenas.

Boost.Tokenizer:

**Autor original**

> Ferruccio https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086/ferruccio

Usando la clase [Boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) se puede hacer este tipo de cosas muy fácilmente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int, char**)
{
    string text = "token, test   string";

    char_separator<char> sep(", ");
    tokenizer< char_separator<char> > tokens(text, sep);
    BOOST_FOREACH (const string& t, tokens) {
        cout << t << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

Updated for C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int, char**)
{
    string text = "token, test   string";

    char_separator<char> sep(", ");
    tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(text, sep);
    for (const auto& t : tokens) {
        cout << t << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

**Autor original**

> KeithB https://stackoverflow.com/users/2298/keithb

Puede usar streams, iteradores, y los algoritmos de copia (copy algorithm) para una implementacion bastante directa.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "The quick brown fox";

  // construct a stream from the string
  std::stringstream strstr(str);

  // use stream iterators to copy the stream to the vector as whitespace separated strings
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(strstr);
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
  std::vector<std::string> results(it, end);

  // send the vector to stdout.
  std::ostream_iterator<std::string> oit(std::cout);
  std::copy(results.begin(), results.end(), oit);
}
```

Comment: ademas de poner el link al usuario, tenes que poner el link al contenido original.

Comment: @Dzyann si revisar la ediciones que se hicieron a mi "pregunta" veras que estaba puesto pero alguin decidio que no deberia de estar, estas wiki fueron creadas con la intencion de que la gente marcara las respuestas que no eran suyas como wiki, ¿lo consegui? pues no lo se. Saludos

Comment: Si alguien lo borro necesitas agregarlo de nuevo, hay gente que no sabe lo que hace. Sino, no sigues las reglas-leyes respecto a como reproducir contenido :S

Answer (score 4):

Una posibilidad es usar [`std::stringstream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) para extraer el texto y guardarlo en una colección de strings:

```
template <typename char_type>
using string_collection = std::vector<std::basic_string<char_type>>;

template <typename char_type>
string_collection<char_type> split(const std::basic_string<char_type> &text)
{
    using string = std::basic_string<char_type>;
    using iterator = std::istream_iterator<string, char_type>;

    std::basic_stringstream<char_type> reader(text);
    return {iterator(reader), iterator()};
}
```

La función `split` del ejemplo anterior se puede usar así:

```
int main()
{
    for (const auto &palabra : split("hola don pepito"))
        std::cout << palabra << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Funciona con cualquier tipo de cadena (`char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` y `char32_t`).

Puedes ver el código funcionando <kbd>[aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BlfliUCnQm4RcMt6)</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Lo mas fácil es usar `getline`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

istringstream is(line);
string part;
while (getline(is, part, ','))
  cout << part << endl;
```