# Leer solo la primera palabra de cin

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes,
estoy escribiendo un programa interactivo dirigido por comandos. Algunos de ellos tienen argumentos pero otros no.

Os dejo el código de mi función `main` para que os hagáis una idea.

```
int main(){
    char comando[10];
    ListaPersonas L = nuevaLista();

    mostrarOrdenes();
    cout << "orden>" << flush;
    cin >> comando;
    normalizar(comando);
    cout << endl;
    while(!sonIguales(comando,"fin")){
        ejecutarOpcion(comando, L);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "orden>" <<flush;
        cin >> comando;
        normalizar(comando);
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

La cuestión es que necesito que en el caso de ser introducido un comando que no requiera de parámetros con algún parámetro de más, este se obviado y solo se ejecute el comando principal; con mi código actual en caso de escribirse un parámetro de más este es interpretado como un nuevo comando introducido, lo cual no deseo.

He estado pruebas con `cin.getline()` con distintos delimitadores pero sin éxito de momento.

Un saludo, muchas gracias y feliz año!

Comment: ¿Podrías poner dos ejemplos de entrada de datos? Creo que quedaría mucho más claro lo que pides viendo casos concretos.

Answer (score 1):

Opino que tu aproximación es incorrecta. Debes leer la entrada del usuario al completo y después procesarla según tus necesidades.

#### Propuesta

Te propongo que leas la entrada del usuario y separes esta entrada en *Comando* y *Parámetros*. Si el *Comando* no requiere parámetros (o son opcionales) lo podrás decidir sobre la marcha. Así pues, crea un objeto que recoja el *Comando* y sus *Parámetros*:

```
struct Comando
{
    std::string Nombre{};
    std::vector<std::string> Parametros{};
};
```

Necesitarás una función que transforme la entrada del usuario en `Comando`, por ejemplo esta:

```
Comando procesar(std::string &entrada)
{
    Comando resultado{};

    if (!entrada.empty())
    {
        normalizar(entrada); // Asumo que normalizar pasa a minúsculas la entrada
        const auto elementos = split(entrada);
        resultado.Nombre = *elementos.begin();
        std::copy(elementos.begin() + 1, elementos.end(), std::back_inserter(resultado.Parametros));
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Lo que hace la función `procesar` es `normalizar` la entrada y luego separar cada una de las palabras entradas por el usuario (para eso uso la función [`split` propuesta en este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2538/2742)), la primera palabra será el *Comando* y las posteriores serían sus *Parámetros*.

Así pues, podrías leer la línea de entrada al completo y decidir en base a lo recibido:

```
std::string entrada{};
std::getline(std::cin, entrada);
auto comando = procesar(entrada);

if (sonIguales(comando.Nombre, "fin") && !comando.Parametros.emtpy()){
    std::cout << "vaya locura! fin va sin parametros!\n";
}
```

#### Notas adicionales.

No uses un array de caracteres (`char comando[10];`) para la lectura de comandos, usa mejor un `std::string`

La orden `std::endl` implica también un `std::flush`.

Una vez tengas el objeto `Comando` puedes trabajar directamente con el mismo, así que la función `ejecutarOpcion` podría recibirlo tal cual:

```
void ejecutarOpcion(const Comando &comando) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar esto para tomar la primera palabra de tu string:

```
sscanf(tuStrinf, "%s%*[^\n]", word);
```

De esta forma sacarías la primera palabra de tu string e ignoraría al resto. Acá te dejo un [manual](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) de tutorialspoint que podría serte de utilidad.

Saludos y feliz año!